# Holy days on the weekend

Tags: number, calendar, chagim-holidays

There are 13 holy days per year on which we must not work (outside of Israel): 2 Rosh Hashanah, 1 Yom Kippur, 4 Sukkot, 4 Pessah, 2 Shavuot. What are the minimum and maximum numbers of these days that fall on the weekend?

I know variations were asked before, but if you can just give me these two numbers I'll be happy.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_of_week_on_Hebrew_calendar#The_four_gates

Comment: The weekend including Friday?

Comment: Not including Friday.

Comment: Double AA, Can you just give me the two numbers?